# UITableView Stops Scrolling After Returning From A DetailView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

[image: UITableView Scrolling iOS StoryBoard]

I am facing a strange issue. I have a simple iPhone app with a TableViewController with custom TableViewCell that is parsing data using NSXmlParser and displaying it. The image inside the cell is loaded with SDWebImage library. Tapping on a cell will push the detail view controller which uses the link to show the post inside the UIWebView. Simple as that.

**PROBLEM:** When i tap on the cell and it shows the UIWebView, after that if i come back to the TableViewController, it stops scrolling. It bounces but doesn't go down where it has already loaded more cells.

I don't know where exactly the problem could be otherwise i would have added the code. Let me know if anybody wants some particular piece of code they want to see in order to find the problem. This is how i am pushing to the detail view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    WebViewController *wvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewController"];
    TheItem *entry = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    wvc.urlString = entry.link;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];
}
```

**UPDATE:** No matter even i select the last cell in the table view, when i come back from the detail view, the position of the scroll is at the top and stuck there.

Comment: How are you pushing the view, and how are you dismissing it?

Comment: @jhilgert00 using didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I have added the code in the question

Comment: also do you have a `viewDidAppear` if so what code is in there?

Comment: @Bot there is no viewDidAppear but there is viewDidLoad. Do you want me to add the code of viewDidLoad?

Comment: Are you preserving selection in the tableview. May or my not help, but I'd try turning on "Clear on Appearance" in the Attributes inspector for your `tableViewController`. I can't see anything wrong with your code, I'd also like to see what's in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @AJ112 Does it scroll fine when you are at the Controller for the first time ?

Comment: @AJ112 no you don't need to show that code. Please show how you are dismissing it. The parent should dismiss the child and not the child dismiss itself. Also where is your elements being stored? is the variable a weak or strong?

Comment: @iphonic yes it does scroll when i am in the tableview controller the first time. It scrolls till end. The problem starts only when i go in to the detail view and come back

Comment: @Bot I am dismissing the detail view by just tapping the back button on the navigation bar available by default when you embed the first view controller inside the navigation controller. and Can you be precise what elements you are talking about? The ones that i am pushing to detail view?

Comment: The variables that store what populates the cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Bot they are declared in the custom tableviewcell class and they are all weak. Also i have added an update, kindly check that might give you some clue

Comment: @AJ112, I'd start with the obvious.  What if your numberOfRowsInSection is answering fewer rows than you expect?  Can you NSLog what it answers and see if the value changes between presenting and dismissing the detail vc?

Comment: @danh just checked by logging the number of rows before and after coming back to tableView. They are 20 and stays 20. I am sure thats not the problem. There are more rows but the scroll is stuck.

Comment: Okay.  The next thing I'd check is heightForRow ...  Does it change?  Maybe log the NSStringFromCGSize(self.tableView.contentSize) when the vc appears.  My bet is something simple that's going to make you slap your forehead when you find it.

Comment: @danh heightForRow is static and set in the StoryBoard as 100. I have even tried adding     self.tableView.rowHeight = 100; in viewDidLoad and it stays 100 all the time. Secondly, shall i use NSStringFromCGSize(self.tableView.contentSize) inside viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear of detailview or listviewcontroller??

Comment: @danh NSStringFromCGSize(self.tableView.contentSize)returns {320, 2000} everytime i come back to the tableview controller. What should be the next step to troubleshoot any other part of the code? I am sure the height of anything has nothing to do with the problem. The scroll is just stuck there and there are cell below the screen

Comment: Hi AJ112, did you get the solution. I am facing same thing not able to find what is going wrong. everything works fine till i not open a new view and after coming back, my tableview scrolling stops though cell and other UI is responding. Thanks in advance